# "Requested store is not found" error in Magento 2.2.7 while opening categories from admin dashboard

Tags: admin, category, stores, magento2.2.7

I am getting an error while trying to open the categories form catalog in the admin dashboard. I have migrated the data from Magento1.9.2.0 to Magento2.2.7.

Getting this in error log.

> "{"0":"Requested store is not found","1":"#0
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(167):
>   "

[image: this is what I am getting on the frontend.]

Comment: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/63#issuecomment-359364023 - check this link